# Word Conversion to Numbers in Dynamic way

Tags: python, string, list, numbers, pysimplegui

Dears,

I'm converting words to numbers than removing vowels, it's working fine except when word are starting with vowel the program stops working ...sounds logic since the tool is removing vowel each time it encouter one of the letters from this list: {'a','e','i','o','u'} , can we get ride of this issue by any trick or idea ?

Example : WORD {'WORD': '**friend**', 'NUMBER': '**6-18-9-5-14**', 'RESULT': '**FRN**'}

For Failed cases, I got the following :

```py
WORD {'WORD': 'a', 'NUMBER': '', 'RESULT': ''}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<FILE_PATH>\Example.py", line 37, in <module>
    result3 = result2[1:] if result2[0].lower() in filter_out else result2
                             ~~~~~~~^^^
**IndexError: string index out of range**
```

```py
    import PySimpleGUI as sg

    alphabet = {'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5','f':'6','g':'7','h':'8','i':'9','j':'10',
    'k':'11','l':'12','m':'13','n':'14','o':'15','p':'16','q':'17','r':'18','s':'19','t':'20',
    'u':'21','v':'22','w':'23','x':'24','y':'25','z':'26'}

    vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u'}

    layout = [

    [sg.Text('Word:', size=(15,1)), sg.Input(enable_events=True, key='WORD', size=(25,1))],
    [sg.Text('Number:', size=(15,1)), sg.Input(key='NUMBER', size=(25,1))],
    [sg.Text('Result:', size=(15,1)), sg.Input(key='RESULT', size=(25,1))],
    ]

    window = sg.Window('MAIN',  layout, finalize=True,element_justification='c')


    while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

    elif event == 'WORD':
        string1 = values['WORD']
        string2 = '-'.join([alphabet[char] if char in alphabet else char for char in string1])
        window['NUMBER'].update(string2)

        result1 = ''.join([letter for letter in string1 if letter.lower() not in vowels])
        result2 = ""
        for i in result1:
            if i.lower() not in result2 and i.upper() not in result2:
                result2 += i
        filter_out = {'d','t'}
        result3 = result2[1:] if result2[0].lower() in filter_out else result2
        result3 = result3[:-1] if result3[-1].lower() in filter_out else result3
        window['RESULT'].update(value=result3.upper())

        window.close()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Programming issue, it happened when `result` is a empty string and you try to get the first char, `resut2[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filter_out` is a dictionary but you are trying to use it as a list. Make it `['d','t']` instead of `{'d','t'}`

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

alphabet = {'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5','f':'6','g':'7','h':'8','i':'9','j':'10',
'k':'11','l':'12','m':'13','n':'14','o':'15','p':'16','q':'17','r':'18','s':'19','t':'20',
'u':'21','v':'22','w':'23','x':'24','y':'25','z':'26'}

vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u'}

layout = [

[sg.Text('Word:', size=(15,1)), sg.Input(enable_events=True, key='WORD', size=(25,1))],
[sg.Text('Number:', size=(15,1)), sg.Input(key='NUMBER', size=(25,1))],
[sg.Text('Result:', size=(15,1)), sg.Input(key='RESULT', size=(25,1))],
]

window = sg.Window('MAIN',  layout, finalize=True,element_justification='c')


while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    #print(event, values)

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

    elif event == 'WORD':        
        
        string1 = values['WORD']
        string2 = '-'.join([alphabet[char] if char in alphabet else char for char in string1])
        window['NUMBER'].update(string2)

        if len(string1) != 0:

            if string1[0] in ['d', 't']:

                string1 = string1[1:]

        if len(string1) != 0:

            if string1[-1] in ['d', 't']:

                string1 = string1[:-1]
        
        result1 = ''.join([letter for letter in string1 if letter.lower() not in vowels])
        result2 = ""
        
        for i in result1:
            if i.lower() not in result2 and i.upper() not in result2:
                result2 += i
            
        window['RESULT'].update(result2.upper())
```

When you type `a` the `result2` is empty, so the it would be `result = ''`. Therefore it gave an `Index Error` when you called it using `result2[1:]`.

Comment: Thanks @KillerRebooted for prompt feedback, I changed that to dictionary as you said but same result, you can try using a word starting with vowel or with ['d','t'], like : addition, task.

Comment: @Hacene2022 Is this the Expected output?

Comment: Exatc!! @KillerRebooted...this is what is expected. Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: Hello @KillerRebooted, sorry to disturb you again, and maybe Jason Yang will comment on that too as the case is answered and still having more questions , probably it's out-of scope:).Want an additional query as I got some non-applicable cases : Is it possible to add here a way to remove those letters only from beginning and end not inside the word, example : for the word textualist , i want to remove only "t" letter at the beginning and end not the one in the middle . When using this script i got : XLS whearase I should get XTLS. Sorry for any inconvinience.

Comment: @Hacene2022 For 'BATTER', Do you want 'BTTR' or 'BTR'

Comment: Thanks for reply, in this case I want "BTR" , the final word should not contain duplicate letters/characters.

Comment: I think it should be fixed now @Hacene2022

Comment: Thanks @KillerRebooted, I'm checking different words combinations to conclude, it should be fine till now, tell me , why you're using this condition 2 times : if len(string1) != 0: ? Lines 33&39.

Comment: Incase if the word is `textualist`, when you start typing `t` it removes `t` and the string becomes "" (Empty) so if I try indexing again, it will give an error

Comment: Ah yes, indeed...this is the magic part of the whole script.